# visual studio unallocted pointer not NULL

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, linked-list, null-pointer

I've encounter an issue in Visual Studio which drives me crazy.
It is regarding unallocated pointers.

I wanted to write a simple linked list app.The problem is that freed and unallocated pointers are not NULL which prevents me from iterating the list.

Consider following C code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <malloc.h> 

typedef struct _item
{
    char data;
    struct _item * pNext;
}item, *pItem;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    pItem listHead;
    pItem listTemp;
    pItem listCurr;

    listHead = (pItem) malloc(sizeof(listHead));
    listHead->data = '0';
    listHead->pNext = NULL; //will create exception in free

    listTemp = listHead;

    while(listTemp->pNext != NULL) //issue 1
    {
        listTemp = listTemp->pNext;//0xfdfdfdfd - never NULL? how to check?
    }

    listCurr = (pItem) malloc(sizeof(listHead));
    listCurr->data = '1';
    listCurr->pNext = NULL; //will create exception in free
    listTemp->pNext = listCurr;

    listTemp = listHead;
    while(listTemp->pNext != NULL)  //issue 2
    {
        printf("%d ", listTemp->data - 48); //"0 "
        listTemp = listTemp->pNext;
    }

    printf("%d ", listTemp->data - 48);
    free(listTemp); //is set to oxfeeefee not to NULL?  //issue 3


    listTemp = listHead;
    while(listTemp->pNext != NULL)  //issue 4
    {
        listTemp = listTemp->pNext;
    }

    free(listTemp);//Not null?

    return 0;
}
```

in line issue 1 and issue 2, listTemp->pNext is not NULL but 0xfdfdfdfd. This prevents from getting the last element in the list
in line issue 3, free doesn't set the freed pointer to null but to 0xfeeefeee. This prevents me from getting last element again.

How can i handle these issues?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Variables are simply uninitialized. The debugger will store a 0xfdfdfdfd pattern in there to help you find places where you forgot to init them. In release builds, no such thing will happen. BTW: Check out `calloc()` and stop casting the returnvalue of such functions in C.

Comment: Ulrich, thanks for the reply. I understood the 0xfdfdfdfd pattern. The problem is, how do i debug my code?

Comment: This is, primarily, a C question, so I've added that tag.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your comments in the code, but free won't set the pointer to NULL.  If you want that you'll need to do it yourself after you call free.

Comment: I can't set it to NULL because when calling free() after setting pNext to NULL will cause exception. This relates to Ulrich Eckhardt response (Visual Studio issue)

Comment: Have you considered setting it to null _after_ calling free()? You have to understand that malloc() returns a value that you must give to free(), where and how you store that value is irrelevant. Setting a pointer to the special value null is just a tool because it allows you to distinguish a pointer to something from a pointer that does not point to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a few issues here. One problem you are having is that you are not allocating enough memory.

```
listHead = (pItem) malloc(sizeof(listHead));
```

`listHead` is a pointer. So you only allocate enough memory to hold a pointer, and not to hold your entire `item` struct. It should be:

```
listHead = (pItem) malloc(sizeof(item));
```

I can't see how issue 1 could ever not be NULL the first time through. Did you step through with a debugger? However, the problem with not allocating enough memory could definitely cause the problem with `free()`, and it's a little difficult to say for sure what other problems it might cause.

Comment: @Erany in the loop you have commented "issue 2", the last item in your list will not be printed, because the last item (validly) has `pNext == NULL`. That is why I said you are parsing the sequence incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax altered slightly to suit my compiler. The two main issues were (1) not allocating enough memory, as already commented. (2) wrong sequence for parsing the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item {
    char data;
    struct item * pNext;
} item, *pItem;

void show (pItem list, int cue) {
    printf("List %d: ", cue);
    while(list != NULL) {
        printf("%c ", list->data); 
        list = list->pNext;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pItem listHead, listTemp, listCurr;

    listHead = malloc(sizeof(item));
    listHead->data = '0';
    listHead->pNext = NULL;
    show(listHead, 1);

    listCurr = malloc(sizeof(item));
    listCurr->data = '1';
    listCurr->pNext = NULL;
    listHead->pNext = listCurr;
    show(listHead, 2);

    printf("Freeing: "); 
    while(listHead != NULL) {
        listTemp = listHead;
        printf("%c ", listHead->data); 
        listHead = listHead->pNext;
        free(listTemp);
    }
    printf("\n");

    show(listHead, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code follows your method of adding the next item to the tail of the list, but I would normally add it before the head and set a new `listHead`.

```
listCurr = malloc(sizeof(item));
listCurr->data = '1';
listCurr->pNext = listHead;
listHead = listCurr;
```

and this will also work for the *first* item provided you initialised `listHead = NULL` to indicate an empty list.

Comment: Did you run it in Visual Studio? Running in debug mode will cause exception in free since you set listCurr->pNext = NULL. This is my major issue

Comment: @Erany my code does not deference or `free()` any pointer when it is `NULL`, or uninitialised.

Comment: @Erany `listCurr->pNext = NULL` indicates the end of the list, this is normal practice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you have to set the pointer to the freed memory to NULL yourself.  The `free` function will only release the memory at the pointer back to the heap.  The pointer parameter is passed by value and cannot be modified by the `free` function itself.

Also, you will need to retain a reference to the previous item in your list, so that when you do free the memory and set the pointer to NULL, you do it in the list items and not on the temporary pointer.

```
listCurr = NULL;
listTemp = listHead;

while(listTemp->pNext != NULL)
{
    listCurr = listTemp;
    listTemp = listTemp->pNext;
}

if(NULL != listCurr)
{
    free(listCurr->pNext);
    listCurr->pNext = NULL;
}
```